# Adobe Photoshop CS3 objects library and scripting

Tags: scripting, photoshop

**Primary question:** I want to make a library of small re-usable objects (eg. passport stamp, specific kind of text etc.) in Adobe Photoshop CS3. What would be best approach to do it? **Secondary question:** Is it possible to change these objects via scripts or c#? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has a javascript interpreter built in.

Here's the API reference: [photoshop_cs3_javascript_ref.pdf](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs3_javascript_ref.pdf)

And here's a tutorial: http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/photoshop-scripts.html